# Is there a terser type enforcing way to accomplish this?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

To handle Include() in my Entity Framework queries I have come up with this:

```
public static IQueryable<AppUser> FindByIdentityUserId(this IQueryable<AppUser> source, int identityUserId, params string[] includes)
{
    var query = source.Where(u => u.IdentityUsersId == identityUserId);
    foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);
    return query;
}
```

Where I then define the includes as follows:

```
public static class AppUserIncludes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Include Following (Organizations), Interests, and Signups.
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] FollowingInterestsSignups => new[]
    {
        nameof(AppUser.Following),
        nameof(AppUser.Interests),
        nameof(AppUser.Signups),
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Include Following (Organizations), Interests, and Signups.
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] FollowingInterestsSignupsAndFollowingNews => new[]
    {
        nameof(AppUser.Following),
        nameof(AppUser.Interests),
        nameof(AppUser.Signups),
        $"{nameof(AppUser.Following)}.{nameof(Organization.News)}",
    };

    // ...
}
```

This has two big problems. The first is there's nothing stopping me from calling it as:

```
var user = dbContext.AppUser.FindByIdentityUserId(23, "this", "is", "not", "valid", "properties");
```

I'd like to have type enforcement.

The second problem is I'd prefer to list each out individually. But boy that would make for a long call. It would look like this:

```
var user = dbContext.AppUser.FindByIdentityUserId("23", AppUserIncludes.Following, AppUserIncludes.Interests, AppUserIncludes.Signups, AppUserIncludes.FollowingThenNews);
```

The third problem is it would be nice to have something (but much shorter) like:

```
AppUserIncludes.Following.OrganizationIncludes.News
```

So I can do the ThenInclude() from each entity rather than having to slowly create every possible combination.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I'm tagging C# as well as EF because fundamentally this is a C# question about how to structure these strings to pass to EF.

Comment: BTW why exactly do you want the `FindByIdentityUserId`? What problem is solved by it's introduction?

Comment: @GuruStron I'm putting all the query logic in an extension method for each entity. It's not terribly useful/important for the FindByIdentityUserId, but it's incredibly valuable for find all events that are in the past and have not been officially closed out that the logged in user is an owner or host of. I put every query in the extension so I don't end up with ones that should be in there, but aren't.

Comment: This is why I never recommend attempting to try and hide EF behind an abstraction. It is just digging a hole that only gets deeper and full of mud when it rains. You don't need code to "handle" includes, EF handles includes. Your callers still need to know what includes they need from what is available. They can do this through `IQueryable` using expressions against the entity, no need to re-invent it. Where I do recommend using patterns like this is enforcing global filtering rules such as an OwnerId for multitenancy, authorization assertions, and/or IsActive checks for soft-delete.

Comment: @StevePy That's going to be some very very very long queries. But you might be right. I do think it's good to have complex queries in a central place so that I can easily reuse them though.

Comment: Yep, and there's nothing wrong with centralizing/standardizing those particular complex queries to make them convenient to call on. Where it can get problematic is if you start wanting everything to be consistent merely for consistency's sake. This either ends up introducing lots of code for dead simple scenarios, or trying to make something overly complex to handle umpteen combinations, defeating the purpose of centralizing out that complexity as the complexity leaks out anyways.

Comment: @StevePy You're advice to date has been spot on so I'm going to unwind this includes stuff. Thanks for the suggestion.